# Limit of a left continuous process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose we are given a left continuous process $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and define

$$Y^n_t=n\int^t_{t-\frac{1}{n}}\mathbf1_{\{|X_{s\vee 0}|\le n\}}X_{s\vee 0}ds$$

Why does it hold that $\lim_nY^n\to X$? It should follow from the left-continuity. Clearly this is important by the definition of the boundaries of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the substitution $u:=n(t-s)$ we obtain 
$$\large Y_t^n=\int_0^1\chi_{\{|X_{t-u/n\vee 0}|\leqslant n\}}X_{t-u/n\vee 0}\mathrm du,$$
and the role of left-continuity is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By left continuity we have $\lim_n X_{t-\frac{u}{n}}=X_t$. But why can I interchange limit and integration? Also, this should just work for left continuous processes. However what exactly fails if we assume right continuity and define $Y_t^n:=\int_t^{t+\frac{1}{n}}\dots$?